# Java - SwingWorker - How to use an arraylist from publish in the EDT

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, swingworker

How do I avoid `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` when accessing a list that is being worked on in another thread (SwingWorker)?

### Details on what I'm trying to use:

- a GUI class which contains this "main" method and I think should run on the EDT.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              new myGUIwithButton();
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- This GUI has a paint method that takes a list of `Words`,a class containing Strings and coordinates, and shows them :

  ```
  public void paint(final List<Word> words){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              // prepare GUI's background, then :
              for(Word word : words){ // <-- this is line 170 in the error shown below
                  // show each word in the GUI
                  // note that I'm not modifying the words list here
              }
  ```
- When pushing a button in the GUI, an instance of a class extending `SwingWorker<List<Word>,List<Word>>` is executed. That creates the working thread as far as I understand. The overridden `doInBackground` method creates a Word list and then publishes it regularly :

  ```
  public List<Word> doInBackground() {
      List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
      while (!isCancelled()) {
          // do some work, define aNewWord
          words.add( aNewWord );
          publish(words);
          Thread.pause(someTime);
      }
      return words;
  }
  ```
- The published words are then automatically sent to the overridden `process` method:

  ```
  protected void process(List< List<Word> > wordss) { // Executed on EDT ! <3
      // I'm taking only the first list that was published to avoid trouble
      List<Word> words = wordss.get(0); 
      myGUI.paint(words);
  }
  ```

### What's the problem?

When the working thread goes "fast" (pause of less than 50ms), I often get an exception for line 170 which is in the `paint` method (the GUI file is called MotsFleches.java):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at MotsFleches$2.run(MotsFleches.java:170)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper$5.dispatchEvent(AtkWrapper.java:700)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

It appears that the `words` list in the `paint` method is being modified while the EDT is working on it. I'm not modifying it there, so it must be from the other thread?
I thought the list was just a "snapshot" of the `words` list in the other thread, since it was sent with the `publish` method. Apparently it's not.
**So what should I change to work in the EDT method with such a "snapshot" of the published list from the `SwingWorker`?**

Thanks for any advice you could provide.

### Notes

- After the exception, the program keeps running fine. I only would like to make it cleaner.
- I tried looking at [Collections.synchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) or even `synchronized (words){...}` but all my attempts failed, most probably because I have no notion of what "synchronism" means in this case and how to use it.
- Note that the `invokeLater` in the paint method seemed useless at first because I always call it from the EDT, however if I don't use it the first call of `paint` doesn't work when the GUI is created (is it because it executes before the GUI despite being called after ?
- I obviously lack many notions, so details will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's slightly difficult to suggest something concrete since the code snippets are fragmented and we have to piece it in ours heads. If you can provide a [mcve] it would be easier. As for the question: you are using the same reference of the list everywhere which is why you get the exception. As a first step, to create a snapshot just manually create a new list inside `doInBackground` and pass that to `publish`. See if that helps.

Comment: I was aware that it's better with a "SSCCE", however I didn't feel capable to do that, because reproducing the problem required the SwingWorker to have a "long" task to do during which it changes the list, so I thought I couldn't simulate it with a pause. Anyway luckily my problem was in the few lines of code I selected. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By publishing the `words` list that is created in the SwingWorker and continue working on the same instance you make this instance subject to synchronization. You should change the `doInBackground` method to create a new `List` for the publish like this:

```
public List<Word> doInBackground() {
  List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
  while (!isCancelled()) {
      // do some work, define aNewWord
      words.add(aNewWord);
      publish(new ArrayList<>(words)); // don't publish words directly but create new list
      Thread.pause(someTime);
  }
  return words;
}
```

With this change the background job and your paint method are working on distinct objects and your problem should be solved.

Comment: It works thanks ! I can't believe I was so close to solving it : before asking, I tried creating a copy in the paint method but it didn't work. It's weird because I just tried and it solves the problem too. I must have done it wrong the first time.

Comment: Creating a new list in paint won't do the trick, as for creating the new list you need to iterate over to old one as well. It will probably reduce the likeliness of the problem to occur, but you will get the Exception from time to time. Actually that is what makes concurrency one of the most difficult aspects of programming. Just by executing your code several times you can't say: I'm sure it works. You need to understand the different paths the threads can take and always assume the worst case.